# If a group contains a subgroup with the order of each of its divisors, is it abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group  that has a subgroup of  size $d$ for every $d$ that divides $|G|$. Must $G$ be abelian?

It can be shown using complete induction that the converse of the above statement is true, but my alg-fu is too underdeveloped to tackle the above problem.

Comment: but if it has uniqe such subgroup for each $d$ , you can say it is cyclic.

Comment: @mesel: one can also strengthen this to: if it has a unique *normal* subgroup for each $d$ - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/885041/115654)

Comment: The various answers, taken together, actually show that *every* non-abelian group of order $<12$ has subgroups of all orders that divide the group order. So if you had started looking for a counterexample, you would very probably have found one. The smallest non-abelian group that doesn't have subgroups of all orders that divide the group order is the alternating group on $4$ objects. It has order $12$ and has no subgroup of order $6$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Choose any nonabelian group of order $pq$ for $p < q$ distinct primes - such a group exists (and is unique) if $p | q - 1$ (e.g. $21$). The divisors of the group order are than $1, p, q$ and $pq$; by Cauchy's theorem, there are subgroups of order $p$ and $q$, since there are elements of these orders.

Alternatively, to be explicit, $S_3$ is a group satisfying this.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the short answer, I am having touble with why there is a unique nonabelian group of order $pq$

Comment: It's constructed using some sort of semidirect product, IIRC. It's given in Dummit and Foote, I know.

Comment: well, I guess the fact that it exists is enough, why is it unique?

Comment: I don't recall off-hand, but it's in D&F. The construction is also given in Hungerford.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the quaternion group.

Answer (score 5):

No, take the quaternion group $Q_8 = \{ \pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k \}$ for example. It has a subgroup of order 2, namely $\{ \pm 1 \}$, it has a subgroup of order 4 e.g. $\{ \pm i \}$ and of course has a subgroup of order 1 and of order 8.

Answer (score 5):

The question of Banarama is an interesting one and refers to the class of finite groups known as *CLT groups*, where CLT stands for *Converse Lagrange Theorem*:

$G$ is a *CLT group* if for each positive integer $d$ dividing $|G|$, $G$ has at least one subgroup of order $d$.

These groups have been studied extensively. It turns out for example that all [supersolvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) groups are CLT, and all CLT groups are [solvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group). See also one of the early [papers](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102983900) of Henry G. Bray, Pac. J. Math 27 (1968).

Answer (score 0):

Dihedral groups, or semidirect product groups of order $p^3$